# rspec generator in rails 3.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I just upgraded to rails 3.2.5 and now when I generate new controllers I don't get rspec tests generated by default.

I can do `rails g controller foo -t rspec`, but I'd prefer to just do `rails g controller foo`.

How do I fix that default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `rails g rspec:install` inside your project folder (presuming you have rspec in your gem file/bundle). That will activate the generators for you.

Mark of [Mark's Blog](http://mallibone.wordpress.com/) has an excellent article on it [here.](http://mallibone.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/getting-started-with-rspec-in-rails-3-2/)